# Calculating $\cos\frac\pi4$ from the half-angle formula gives $\sqrt{\frac12}$ instead of $\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$. What went wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

I am using the formula $$\cos\left(\frac x2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}2}$$ to find $\cos\left(\frac{pi}{4}\right)$ but it does not give me the correct result.

$$
\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
= \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}2}
= \sqrt{\frac{1+0}2}
= \sqrt{\frac12}
$$

This contradicts $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Exercises: rationalise the denominator of $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$. Now try $\frac{1}{3-2\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing: $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2=\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt4}=\sqrt{\dfrac24}=\sqrt{\dfrac12}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt {\frac 12} = \frac{\sqrt 1} {\sqrt 2} = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} =  \frac {\sqrt 2} {\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2} =  \frac {\sqrt 2} {2} $

This process is called 'rationalising the denominator' and you should try to do this when the denominator is an algebraic irrational number.